# Intuition behind Wigner rotation of spin component under boost

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

I am currently reading Weinberg's Quantum Field Theory Vol. 1 foundations, Ch.2 (available here http://quantum.phys.unm.edu/500-23/WeinbergQTFI.pdf).

My question is related to the intuition behind equation 2.5.23 and 2.5.10 reproduced below
[image: Transformation law of spin under boost]

My understanding of the equation is as follow:  the effect of a boost on a particle having some momentum $p$ and spin is to rotate the spin by a so called "Wigner rotation" where the Wigner rotation is the effective rotation obtained by doing the following series of lorentz transformations:

- Go from rest frame momentum ($k$) to p ($L(p)$ as defined by weinberg)
- Go from p to $\Lambda p$ ($\Lambda$)
- Go from $\Lambda p$ to $k$ ($L^{-1}(\Lambda p)$)

What is the intuition behind the connection between boost to wigner rotation?  My understanding is wigner rotations happen because non-collinear boosts induce a rotation.  In this case, the non-collinearity of $p$ and the boost ($\Lambda$) causes the spin to rotate.  But I don't have a clear intuition why the formula other than boosts generators algebra don't close and somehow have to do with rotations...

Similarly, suppose we constructed a mechanical model of spin (consider the object as having finite radius and some moment of inertia and spinning and with momentum p).  Would the angular momentum in a boosted frame also rotate the same way it is claimed here in the spin = 1 representation? (by the wigner rotation), or is this formula a purely quantum mechanical effect.

Comment: Use MathJax, not images.